Unitary orbit of a positive operator
Let $P\in\mathcal{B(\mathcal{H})}$ be a positive contraction. Suppose it is given that $P\cdot \max\{\lambda,P\}^{-1}$ is unitarily equivalent to $P$ for all $0 < \lambda < 1$. Then is it necessarily true that $P$ is a projection?

No. Let $H = L^2([0, 1]) \oplus \ell^2$. Then $P = M_x \oplus 1_{\ell^2}$, where $M_x$ is the multiplication by $x$ operator on $L^2([0, 1])$, is a counterexample, as,
$$P \cdot \max\{\lambda, P\}^{-1} = M_{\lambda^{-1}x} \oplus 1_{L^2([\lambda, 1]) \oplus \ell^2}, \text{ acting on }L^2([0, \lambda]) \oplus L^2([\lambda, 1]) \oplus \ell^2$$
is easily seen to be unitarily equivalent to $P$, for all $0 < \lambda < 1$.

My advice to the OP: this kind of condition is quite unlikely to work, unless you found it in a textbook or a research paper somewhere. I don’t think it’s that helpful to just throw out and try your luck with this, unless you have a really compelling reason to suspect it will work.
